# regex_search don't recognize parenthese

Tags: regex, brackets

why `regex_search(line, smatch, tofind)` don't find the expression 
    `"toto (titi)"`
because of the bracket? Without bracket it works. How to remplace ( by a pattern that match this?

Answer (score -1):

You have to escape parenthesis (there are used for grouping):

```
"toto \\(titi\\)"
```

or, with raw string (C++):

```
R"(toto \(titi\))"
```

Comment: find! the solution is (toto \(titi\ tata\))